# Free collaborative tweeting

Tags: twitter

I would like to let my friends tweet using my Twitter handle but I want to be able to moderate their tweets before they go out. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t do it through the Twitter apps (to my knowledge, at least), but you could (potentially—I haven’t used it) the third-party client [Birdhouse](http://birdhouseapp.com).

> **Capture your ideas, refine them later, publish when ready**
>
> Ever think of something for your Twitter that you don't want to post right away? Birdhouse is the perfect place to put it.